# What sequence of polynomials is equal to $2^n$ for integers $1$ to $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polynomials

I am trying to prove to someone that no matter how many terms you have of a sequence you can never be 100% sure of the underlying formula.
Consider this sequence:
$$2^n=1,2,4,8,16,...$$ But just given the sequence $1,2,4,8,16,...$ we can't be sure that it was generated by $2^n$. For instance the sequence dividing a circle using Chords is identical for the first 5 terms but diverges at the 6th: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyChords.html 
The polynomial for it is ${1\over24} (n^4-6n^3+23n^2-18n+24)$
Circle division terms$=1,2,4,8,16,31...$
but $2^n=1,2,4,8,16,32...$
What sequence of polynomials will match match 2^n for an arbritrary number of terms say $k$ terms before diverging on the $(k+1)^{th}$ term.

Comment: Well you can always fit $n$ points to a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Comment: Are you already familiar with [Lagrange interpolation polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)?

Comment: @Gregory: Yes that's what I am trying to do. I just need to know how to calculate the polynomial for each n points. I could enter the powers of 2 into an excel spreadsheet for instance and find a $n^th$ degree polynomial on the chart that would match. I am hoping for a more direct way to do it.

Comment: @g.sassatelli I am familiar with those. Those would take a lot of computations for large values of n like 50 wouldn't they?

Comment: The answer is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation

Comment: @MathMan Yes, they would, to the point that Gregory's method is most likely faster.

Comment: @Gregory That is an interesting article, some of which I partly understand. Is the polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{ \left( \prod_{0\le j\le n,j\neq i}{{x-x_j}\over x_i-x_j} \right) }y_i$ the one to plug into?

Comment: @MathMan Yes, if you plug in the value $x_0$ you'll see how it works.  It's a polynomial in one variable because $x$ is always in the numerator, everything else is constant.

Comment: @Gregory plugging in $x_0=0,x_1=1,y_0=0,y_1=1$ gives me $y=x+1$ which is right. But that will take a long time if I want to do a large number of terms such as 50. Do you know a way to do it on a TI-89 calculator or in Excel or OpenOffice Calc or in Maple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could formulate a recusion starting with $p_0(x)=1$ let
$$p_{k+1}(x)=2p_k(x-1)+\frac{1-2p_k(-1)}{k!}(1-x)(2-x)\cdots(k-x) $$

Comment: That works and does what I need: I don't understand how or why it works though or how to prove it will work for all powers of the series.